# Prevent double tap closing behavior on jQuery Mobile Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, double-click

I'm using jQuery Mobile to create a popup near an info image button (see picture below). The popup I'm creating has `data-dismissable` set as `false`. In red it has been highlighted the container created by jQuery Mobile.

[image]

If the user taps once on *i* icon, it works perfectly. The popup opens and `popupafteropen` event is called. To dismiss it, the user can tap (click) on the *i* or outside the red area (thanks to `data-dismissable` value). On the contrary, if the users performs a double tap (here I mean that the delay bewteen two taps is very short), the popup opens, `popupafteropen` is called but then also `close` is called (due to the second tap and `data-dismissable` value). The overall result is that the popup is not shown.

Are there any solutions to adopt? My goal is to prevent the second tap in order to display the popup correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kazekage Gaara has a good idea so look first at it.

Other one would require you to bind a doubletap event to popup opening icon and prevent default action, unfortunately jQuery Mobile don't have support for doubletap so you can use this plugin:

```
(function($) {
     $.fn.doubleTap = function(doubleTapCallback) {
         return this.each(function(){
            var elm = this;
            var lastTap = 0;
            $(elm).bind('vmousedown', function (e) {
                                var now = (new Date()).valueOf();
                var diff = (now - lastTap);
                                lastTap = now ;
                                if (diff < 250) {
                            if($.isFunction( doubleTapCallback ))
                            {
                               doubleTapCallback.call(elm);
                            }
                                }      
            });
         });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and bind it like this:

```
$(".icon").doubleTap(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

There used to be much easier solution for this, jQUery Mobile used to have mobileinit configuration parameter that allowed you to set how long tap event can last.

Or you can monitor interval between taps and prevent allow actions, like this:

```
var lastTapTime;
function isJqmGhostClick(event) {
    var currTapTime = new Date().getTime();

    if(lastTapTime == null || currTapTime > (lastTapTime + 800)) {
        lastTapTime = currTapTime;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing something here... *There used to be much easier solution for this, jQUery Mobile used to have mobileinit configuration parameter that allowed you to set how long tap event can last.*

Comment: Older versions of jQuery Mobile had an configuration parameter (through mobileinit) which you could use to set how long you can press a screen before tap event triggers. So you could have set that everything under 1 sec counts as tap. And I just realized that this would not help you at all, your case would still trigger twice. :D

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about FastClick, it doesn't do anything here

Comment: Hm can you create an easy jSFiddle example, just icon and popup?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. it's a bit complex to provide an example. Since there is also a problem when tapping (taps are not always captured), I'm thinking that backbone events delegate mechanism could be the problem. I'll try to do some tests.

Comment: Oh that's an unholy combination, at one point I was thinking of leaving jQuery Mobile because of how it works bad with Backbone.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the event and ignore it if the popup is already open. Something like :

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.find("#popupID").is(":visible") {
  // Do something here if the popup is open
  }
```